# Growing Rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a growing rectangle drawn on top of a TableLayoutPanel but when it grows it causes a horrible flicker even with Double Buffer.

I am using e.Graphics.FillRectangle and a global variable that increases the size of the rectangle. I set up a timer to make it grow every 1/10th of a second by 1 pixel. Why does it flicker so much and how can I stop the flicker?

```
 int grow = 100;
    private void tableLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, (tableLayoutPanel1.Width-grow)/2, (tableLayoutPanel1.Height-grow)/2, grow,grow);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grow += 10;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Refresh();
    }
```

In order to rule out all other possibilities I removed everything from my program and started from scratch with just a growing rectangle and it still creates this horrible flicker.

Comment: Could you provide the code?Setting DoubleBuffer to true doesn't help always.

Comment: Sure I will try to simplify the code so you don't get trailed all over the place thinking the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Nikola added the code, just create a Timer and a TableLayoutPanel and pop the code in a fresh project and you should see the flicker.

Comment: Your example is not flickering for me. Not even with 10ms timer and 1 pixel per tick.

Comment: I don't think filling only a `Rectangle` with size growing can flicker? Are you sure? Painting on your form or some another control?

Comment: dognose you probably made it too small make sure you dock the TableLayoutPanel and maximize your form. Guarantee it will flicker for you if you are using .net 4.0 and my exact code.

Comment: King King that is why I first avoided posting my code because I know for certain drawing a filled rectangle is causing the flicker. I made a separate program from scratch just with this code to prove it as well.

Comment: @CodeCamper No, not even with a "FullHD" Sized window.

Comment: Are you using .net 4.0? Nikola figured out why it is occurring the `OnPaintBackground` is running before the `Paint` and this is definitely the problem. It loads the background without the rectangle then it loads the rectangle causing a horrible flicker. I am not sure why you are not experiencing it I checked it on a television as well as a computer monitor on 2 different computers and made a separate program just to see if it was other things in my program.

Comment: TLP is a *container control*, it doesn't have its DoubleBuffered property set to true.  Since it is just supposed to be a window that keeps track of its child controls and has little reason to draw anything but its BackColor.  The bigger question here is why you selected TLP.  A PictureBox would be a better choice, it is double-buffered by default.

Comment: Why do you use `Refresh`? why not `Invalidate`? `Invalidate` would be better.

Comment: I tested and using `Refresh` is some part of your problem, using `Invalidate()` causes little flicker and it looks OK.

Comment: @HansPassant I am using a TLP because I have many controls contained inside it. The TLP produces a small spacing between the controls and I am using that spacing to draw colors between the controls. My only issue I was having was the flickering.

Comment: @KingKing I used Invalidate and Refresh before I asked this question but I went back to Refresh because it didn't make a difference. I want no flicker not some flicker. Although after seeing all the suggestions I changed my Refresh to Invalidate just for good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is the code. You first need to make background buffer Bitmap with the size of your control. After that, you will need to draw everything on the Bitmap, and than draw that bitmap onto the control.

```
Bitmap backBuffer = null;
int grow = 100;
private void tableLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (backBuffer == null)
        backBuffer = new Bitmap(tableLayoutPanel1.Width, tableLayoutPanel1.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(backBuffer);
    g.Clear(tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor);
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, (tableLayoutPanel1.Width - grow) / 2, (tableLayoutPanel1.Height - grow) / 2, grow, grow);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, backBuffer.Width, backBuffer.Height);
    g.Dispose();
}
private void tableLayoutPanel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backBuffer = null;
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grow += 10;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Invalidate();
}
```

Note that you will need to create new `Bitmap` each time you resize the `TableLayoutPanel`. In addition I suggest using `Invalidate()` instead of `Refresh()`.

But this will still include some potential flickering. In order to completely avoid flicker, in addition to the previous code, you will need to subclass the `TableLayoutPanel` and override the `OnPaintBackground()` method in such a way that `base.OnPaintBackground` is never called. This way way won't have any flickering at all. The reason why you have the flickering is because the background is redrawn before your `Rectangle`, any time you draw it. Switch the original `TableLayoutPanel` class with this `BackgroundlessTableLayoutPanel`

```
public class BackgroundlessTableLayoutPanel : TableLayoutPanel
{
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I enjoyed learning of this new bitmap buffer concept but it appears you hit the real nail right on the head. The `OnPaintBackground` triggers before the Paint method and causes a flicker which is unrelated to performance. Could you elaborate more on how you would modify OnPaintBackGround because when I do it I see a frozen copy of my desktop in my form.

Comment: Disabling OnPaintBackground has many unintended consequences but it is the root of the problem so what is the best way to resolve this? If I simply disable it then dragging my form off screen creates a frozen effect and duplicates the background...

Comment: Clear the bitmap with some background color  each time before drawing the Rectangle so the backbuffer can serve as your background.

Comment: @CodeCamper I've edited the answer, add the `g.Clear(tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor);` before the DrawRectangle call, this should mitigate your problem with the background.

Comment: Has anyone done with this code OK? I've tested but the flicker is still there.

Comment: This is how it should be done. This is the standard approach for double buffering. I must point out that TableLayoutPanel isn't the best choice as canvas for drawing, as @HansPassant stated. The best choice would be PictureBox but the regular Panel would be OK of the background drawing is prevented.

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic the only reason I am using the TLP is because I actually am using it to contain controls. The reason I am drawing on the TLP is because there is spacing between each control and I wanted to draw colors in between to represent some information about the controls relation to each other. My only issue was this flicker.

Answer (score -1):

Most controls have a [Paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event where you can implement any custom drawing you need to do. It is also possible to implement your own control where you override the [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cksxshce.aspx) method. [See the article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxys6ytf.aspx).

Both these should give ok results.

Comment: No they don't need to, if the panel redraws its background, on slower computers you can experience flickering, drawing in a back buffer bitmap can solve the problem. I addition, since the OP uses e.Graphics, I assume he already uses the Paint event handler.

Comment: Perfect, Great, Good, Mediocre, [ok], Bad. Now I just need to remove the flicker. Nikola, I would appreciate some help using bitmap to remove this flicker as I am trying to do a little dynamic animation in my winform.